# HDMI/DisplayPort - HDA NVidia no sound

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, sound, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, and I found the monitor can't play sounds. I connect my monitor with HDMI-HDMI cable. The sound settings are shown below:

[image: Digital Stereo HDMI output selected]

Then I installed `pavucontrol`, which shows these settings:

[image: Output Devices - HDMI DisplayPort (plugged in)]

I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I fixed this problem by following the steps of installing the NVIDIA Driver.

After I installed NVIDIA Driver and reboot, I found my monitor could play sounds.

What a surprise! I installed the NVIDIA Driver for CUDA, but it fixed my sounds issue!

Comment: actually I have no idea which step works for this issue. but it worked somehow